# How to implement a non-blocking Timer with GWT

Tags: gwt

I have this existing Timer function:

```
            final Timer waveTimer = new Timer() {
                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    double value = r.getByte(); // takes quite long to finish
                    wave.renderWaveOnFly(value);
            }};
            waveTimer.scheduleRepeating(50);
```

However it works, the UI is "blocked" and that user can't click and do anything in the UI until the timer finishes when part of the UI calls `waveTimer.cancel()` which I created another Timer that cancels this timer after 10 seconds, so the UI is not usable until then.

Is there a way to implement a non-blocking timer such that it would pause for some time, perhaps just to make sure that the UI is not blocked and the user can still do something in the UI.

I mean, still have the feel that the UI is still responsive.

I am not sure about the figure, but say like every 100 millisec it stops and then give way for the UI and resume 100 millisec after the pause or something like this. I am thinking what approach to deal with.

Comment: One should not do any costly operations in a UI thread! Use a separate thread for that. Or if ti can not be circumvented, display a "Loading..."/"Please wait..." screen, ideally along with a progress indicator .

Comment: @ppeterka I wish I could do that, but my application's function is to render a waveform out of the real-time bytes it gets from the flash object (of course wrapped with javascript)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590850/threading-in-gwt-client

Comment: What is the package for the Timer you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do computations out of the UI thread in the browser is to use [WebWorkers](http://caniuse.com/webworkers). There's no facility to use them in GWT though: worker code requires a specialized GWT linker, and creating a WebWorker is only possible through JSNI.

FYI, [SpeedTracer](http://code.google.com/p/speedtracer/) uses WebWorkers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change *getBytes()* method to be a asynchronous call ? Then the UI should not hang waiting for the method to finish.