# GWT client side multithreading revisited

Tags: multithreading, gwt

I am converting a swing application to GWT, that made heavy use of multithreading. The code runs a continuous numerical simulation in the background, and displays results graphically each frame. The simulation needs to know how much **real** time elapses on each calculation.

### Swing

```
Thread calculate = new Thread(new Runnable(){
  // run calculation cycles every 10 ms 
  // (or as fast as possible)
  long prevT=System.currentTimeMillis();
  while(!isFinished){
    long currT = System.currentTimeMillis(),
         dt    = currT-prevT;
    if(dt<10)      Thread.sleep(5);
    else{
      simulate(dt);  
      prevT = currT;
    }
  }
}
// Update UI every 60 ms
java.awt.Timer timer = new Timer(60, new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  results = getCurrentSimState();
  uiPanel.render(results);
}});
```

Additionally there is event-driven code from the user that changes the simulator state.

What is the best way to implement this in GWT? Most previous multithreading questions relate primarily to async client-server work. I saw this question [Threading in GWT (Client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590850/threading-in-gwt-client) and I wondered if a  `Scheduler` would be appropriate:

### GWT

```
void onLoad(){
  AnimationScheduler.get().requestAnimationFrame(callback, uiElement);
}
AnimationCallback cb = new AnimationCallback(){public void execute(double t){
  results = getCurrentSimState();
  render(results, uiElement);
  AnimationScheduler.get().requestAnimationFrame(callback, uiElement);
}};
double prevT=Duration.currentTimeMillis();
Scheduler.get().scheduleIncremental(new RepeatingCommand(){ public void execute() {
  double currT = Duration.currentTimeMillis(),
         dt    = currT-prevT;
  if(dt>30){
    calculate(dt);
    prevT = currT;
  }
  return isFinished;
}});
```

As I'm completely new to GWT, I'd really like to know if

1. is this a feasible design? It is very confusing going from threaded to event-driven design.
2. I've no idea which one is likely to be "ticking" faster. Which of the two things gets prioritised? The calculation in the `RepeatingCommand`, or the GUI update in the `AnimationScheduler`?
3. Are there any major caveats with this design? I don't want the page to lock up! I arbitrarily chose to use different ways of scheduling for the two threads -- is that correct? And if so why?
4. 10 ms might be to fast, but is there a way of guessing what a sensible calculation rate is? The simulator is more accurate the faster it can be updated. (It is a system of stiff PDEs solved by RK4!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "simulating" multi-threading with Scheduler, you may want to consider using real background processing with Web Workers.

Note that with an Incremental command in Scheduler, you have to return "false" when the work is finished, or "true" when it needs to continue. This command will only work if you can split your calculations in small chunks, and then give back control to JavaScript between the chunks that it can execute user actions.

If you can't split the work in small chunks, the approach with a Scheduler will only work if each calculation cycle takes less time than the interval between calculations, giving JavaScript a chance to react to user activity between the calculations.

Comment: Thanks - web workers was exactly what I needed, I hadn't come across these before. I eventually came across the google code `WebWorker` linker which seems to do exactly what I need.